# How to bind string variable to Datagrid row details which is bound to DataSet

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have Datagrid which is bound to my Database

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Row="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainSearchBinding}" />
```

And I have row details which is bound to the Intro column of my table in database

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>            
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" >
                    <TextBlock Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="13" 
                    Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Intro}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

What I want is **not** to use Intro column in my table. I want to use string value from my code instead of column Intro. How can I bind string value to my row details? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my xaml code a little bit add Name to Text Block.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="14"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="rowdetails" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>


            </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

And the in code behind I add this code below to OnMouseClick. retString is my string variable. It is showing my string variable in each clicked row details.

```
 Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow row = (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)(DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DataGrid1.SelectedItem));

            // Getting the ContentPresenter of the row details
            DataGridDetailsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridDetailsPresenter>(row);


            DataTemplate template = presenter.ContentTemplate;
            TextBlock txt = (TextBlock)template.FindName("rowdetails", presenter);
            txt.Text = retString;
```

Do not forget to add FindVisualChild in your code. Here is the code.

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is childItem)
                    return (childItem)child;
                else
                {
                    childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null)
                        return childOfChild;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I do not know why nobody answered to my question. Maybe it is not popular.